# redux-saga injected twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, action, redux-saga

I have a redux-saga which is called once, but it is executing twice.

This is the action that starts the saga:

```
export function createRequest (data) {
  return {
    type: CREATE_REQUEST,
    payload: {data}
  };
}
```

and my sagas.js file looks this way:

```
export function* create (x) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(request, URL_TO_API, Object.assign({}, buildBaseHeaders('en'), {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(x.payload.data)
    }));
    yield put(createSuccess(response));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(createFailure(error));
  }
}

... my other sagas

export default function* defaultSaga () {
  yield takeLatest(CREATE_REQUEST, create);
  ... my other calls
}
```

The way I'm injecting the sagas into my React component is this:

```
const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
const withReducer = injectReducer({key: 'myComponent', reducer});
const withSaga = injectSaga({key: 'myComponent', saga});

export default compose(withReducer, withSaga, withConnect) MyComponent;
```

But the saga is injected twice. So, what am I missing here? How can I inject the saga only once no matter on how many times MyComponent gets rendered?

Comment: Who calls the createSaga? If it runs twice and one fails then it's OK to be console'ing only once the create function. I'm missing the whole picture here :/

Comment: The saga `create` is called through the `createRequest` action. That action is used once, but the saga is called twice.

Comment: Oh OK, now I am out of ideas :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the saga is injected twice. So, what am I missing here?

Solution is dependent on how `redux-sagas-injector` npm library works. In general case, asynchronous loading and applying for sagas is difficult thing, because `saga` is consists of "live" process manager, which can not be disposed on some function call or object deletion.
It implies from saga's ability to launch custom tick callback domains (Promises, AJAX/XHR, `setImmediate`, etc), which can not be disposed from custom external code (That's also reason, why HMR does not work with `sagas` in partial mode and should reload whole page).

So, if you perform `saga` injection on router switching, check two things: that old saga has implicit action to dispose from outer side, like special inner technical dispose action, and that there is not misconfiguration in router side - maybe same page had been launched, for example, twice.